# removing the current view from the tabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, ios4

hi how to remove the current view displayed on tabbar controller. the view is added using [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:myView.view]. What should be done in myView to remove this view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

`[myView.view removeFromSuperview];`